# Abrir un modal desde un select

Tags: php, javascript, html, phpmyadmin

estoy imprimiendo el siguiente select opt

```
<select id="select_ic"><?php ?>
  <option data-toggle="modal" 
    data-idsubseccion="<?php echo $id_sub_seccion ?>"
    type="option"
    class="btn btn-default"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#anadir_pregunta">Añadir pregunta <?php echo $id_sub_seccion ?>
  </option>
</select>
```

al cual le estoy pasando mediante el data-target el siguiente id **anadir_pregunta** para que me responda al siguiente modal

```
<form id="guardarDatos"> 
<div class="modal fade" id="anadir_pregunta" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
 aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
     label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Agregar el contenido que 
    contendra tu pregunta</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="datos_ajax_register"></div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nombre0" class="control-label">Pregunta:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre0" name="nombre" required maxlength="45">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id" name="id">
      </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar datos</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

En donde mi codigo Script es el siguiente...

```
$('#anadir_pregunta').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Botón que activó el modal
        var id = button.data('id') // Extraer la información de atributos de datos
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('#id').val(id)
        alert(id);
    })
```

estoy tratando de que mi modal responda cuando le doy selectOption

Comment: Cual es tu pregunta o problema?

Comment: no me abre el modal cuando oprimo el select al que le estoy asignando el modal

Comment: @jDanielSotoC agrega eso a tu pregunta, porque en la misma pregunta no estas especificando cual es tu problema o a que quieres llegar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede usar el evento onchange , al cambiar o seleccion una opcion del select invocar una funcion y enviar el valor del select algo asi:
**html:**

```
<select id="select_ic"onchange="abrirModal($(this).val());">
<option data-toggle="modal" data-idsubseccion="<?php echo $my_data ?>>Añadir pregunta></option>
</select>
```

**javascript:**

```
function abrirModal(select_id){
$("#idInput").val(select_id);//asigna data a modal por id
$('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

es un ejemplo puedes hacer de muchas formas !!